# How to convert AudioClassification model ced-tiny to android?

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, pytorch

How to convert AudioClassification model ced-tiny and it's CedFeatureExtractor to android tensorflow lite or Pytorch Mobile and use it in java?

ced-tiny: https://huggingface.co/mispeech/ced-tiny